# How can I batch process scanned images and remove dust and specs?

Tags: php, linux, image-processing

I have a constant stream of scanned images from slides, negatives, and photographs.  I would like to programmatically batch process these to remove dust, dirt, and marks.  At the same time I'd like to apply some other photo filters that behave like Photoshop's auto color and auto contrast.

Are there any PHP or Linux applications or libraries available that I can build into my system to do this processing?

Comment: Why don't you just do a batch process in Photoshop?

Comment: You can investigate [tag:gimp], which can be used in scripted/headless mode; and possibly reuse some photoshop filters even.

Comment: You sound like a [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), and specifically [Magickwand](http://www.magickwand.org/) can do that, but you'll need to know what you want to implement. There is no filter that can automatically remove general 'dust, dirt and marks', but you can find filters that can enhance some images automatically.

Comment: Which MagickWand command gets us close to achieving spec removal?